# How to suppress Javascript errors thrown in WebBrowserControl Print method.

Tags: javascript, browser, controls

I have a windows c# application that uses WebBrowser Control to navigate to a webpage. I use WebBrowser.Print() to silent print this web page. Now i get some Java Script errors while printing. Is it possible to suppress these. 
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true; doesnt seem to work as these errors occur only when printing the webpage.

Thanks,
Rajee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about c# actually, but generally speaking web browsers report errors into the console only when the error event has bubbled up the DOM all the way up to the `window` while not being handled on its way up. If you bind a Javascript handler to `"error"` and prevent its further propagation, it then won't reach the document-bound default handler and supress all further errors from being reported into the console.

This is the simplest Javascript example:

```
window.onerror = function(){
    // Returning true informs the browser,
    // that the error has been taken care of
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a try catch on the method.